# Unable to update with where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

my query is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateMenu] 
@MenuName VARCHAR(100),
@MenuType VARCHAR(50),
@IsDefault BIT,
@PortalID INT,
@MenuID INT 
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@IsDefault = 1)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE  [dbo].[MENU] set IsDefault = 0 where IsDefault= 1 and PortalID=@PortalID,
                        MenuName =@MenuName,
                        IsDefault=@IsDefault
                        MenuType = @MenuType where MenuID=@MenuID

            END
    ELSE
            BEGIN
                    UPDATE  [dbo].[MENU] set 
                        MenuName =@MenuName,
                        IsDefault=@IsDefault
                        MenuType = @MenuType 
                      where MenuID=@MenuID
            END


END
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

its only part of procedure.I know `where` condition is not use twice just as i want to try.But unable to handle the situation.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateMenu] 
@MenuName VARCHAR(100),
@MenuType VARCHAR(50),
@IsDefault BIT,
@PortalID INT,
@MenuID INT 
AS
BEGIN

  UPDATE  [dbo].[MENU] SET
    MenuName = @MenuName,
    IsDefault= CASE WHEN PortalID = @PortalID THEN 0 ELSE @IsDefault END,
    MenuType = @MenuType 
  WHERE MenuID=@MenuID

END
```

It will set the value of `IsDefault` to `0` if `PortalID = @PortalID` otherwise `IsDefault` will have the value of parameter `@IsDefault`.

Answer (score 2):

This query is malformed. Try

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[MENU] 
set IsDefault = 0 
WHERE IsDefault= 1 
  and PortalID=@PortalID
  and MenuName =@MenuName
--  and IsDefault=@IsDefault
  and MenuType = @MenuType 
  and MenuID=@MenuID
```

---

to align with your updated question:

```
BEGIN
    IF(@IsDefault = 1)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE  [dbo].[MENU] set IsDefault = 0 
                  where IsDefault= 1 and 
                        PortalID=@PortalID and
                        MenuName =@MenuName and
                        IsDefault=@IsDefault and
                        MenuType = @MenuType and 
                        MenuID=@MenuID

            END
    ELSE
            BEGIN
                    UPDATE  [dbo].[MENU] set 
                        MenuName =@MenuName,
                        IsDefault=@IsDefault,
                        MenuType = @MenuType 
                      where MenuID=@MenuID
            END


END
```

Comment: my whole situation is as per above.I modify my question plz suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multipe `WHERE` clauses in an `UPDATE` statement. You have to combine the conditions either with `AND` or with `OR`. `,` is no valid operator to combine them.

See Mattens answer for a sample.

Comment: This should be a comment on Matten's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use goto with labels:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateMenu]   
@MenuName VARCHAR(100),  
@MenuType VARCHAR(50),  
@IsDefault BIT,  
@PortalID INT,  
@MenuID INT   
AS  

IF @IsDefault = 1 GOTO Update2

--------
Update1:
--------
UPDATE  [dbo].[MENU] 
SET
MenuName =@MenuName,                          
MenuType = @MenuType                         
where MenuID=@MenuID              

GOTO EndProcessing

--------
Update2:
--------
UPDATE  [dbo].[MENU] 
SET
IsDefault = 0
MenuName =@MenuName,                          
MenuType = @MenuType                         
where MenuID=@MenuID              
and PortalID=@PortalID

--------------
EndProcessing:
--------------

SET ANSINULLS ON
```

Answer (score 0):

My best reading is:

- if a specific item is about to be set as default, reset that attribute for the current default item;
- afterwards just proceed with the update of the specified item.

So...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateMenu] 
  @MenuName  VARCHAR(100),
  @MenuType  VARCHAR(50),
  @IsDefault BIT,
  @PortalID  INT,
  @MenuID    INT 
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@IsDefault = 1)
    UPDATE [dbo].[MENU]
    SET IsDefault = 0
    WHERE IsDefault= 1
      AND PortalID=@PortalID
  ;
  UPDATE [dbo].[MENU]
  SET
    MenuName  = @MenuName,
    IsDefault = @IsDefault
    MenuType  = @MenuType
  WHERE MenuID = @MenuID
  ;
END
```

So, if you have specified `1` as the value of `@IsDefault`, the procedure will perform two updates, otherwise just one.